# How early can you go through security at London Luton Airport?

Tags: air-travel, uk, airports, london

I have a 07:15 flight on Sunday Oct 28th departing from London Luton Airport. Owing to limited options on public transport, I will be arriving at the airport at ~00:30. Is there any chance I will be able to go through security earlier than the usual 3h and wait for my flight in duty free?

**Edit**: I have no checked bags - only carry-on. It is an international flight to a destination outside of the EU.

Comment: @AnnaSchumann I’ve been allowed to clear security early to accompany my partner whose flight was leaving a couple of hours before mine, after asking the Officer very nicely for permission. I suspect you may need a better reason than ‘I had to arrive very early due to public transport’ but you may be lucky - no harm asking!

Comment: Is the airport open through the night?

Comment: @Willeke Yes, Luton is open 24/7 (see third question in this [FAQ](https://www.london-luton.co.uk/help-advice?category=Being+at+LLA))

Comment: @AnnaSchumann This does not directly answers your question - I just wanted to check if none of the [coaches](https://www.nationalexpress.com/en/airports/luton) are good options for you to get to Luton Airport. This is a great question on its own.

Comment: @B.Liu Unfortunately, i'm already booked on the latest possible coach from my area!

Comment: While most of the interesting things at Luton are past security; there are places you can kill time before going through: https://www.london-luton.co.uk/inside-lla/map-of-inside-lla

Answer (score 84):

I was finally able to get into contact with London Luton Airport, who stated that i'd be able to pass through security ~5h before departure - which is the point at which the airline activates the flight.

Comment: Thanks for coming back to answer your question!

Comment: If you intend o get some sleep during your waiting hours, please check a guide [like this](https://www.sleepinginairports.net/guides/london-luton-airport-guide.htm)

Answer (score 9):

Be aware that Luton airport is pretty grim generally; it's a permanant building site and there is very little to do before security. I had a similar transport issue and had to wait until 2 hours before my flight before I could go through. There's also a shortage of seating before security.

Comment: This sounds like a useful comment, but it doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev The second sentence "I ... had to wait until 2 hours before my flight" seems a pretty unambiguous answer to me (even if it does contradict the advice from Luton Airport).

Comment: On the other hand, it's less grim than Luton itself.

Comment: This answer seems to imply that there are positive qualities to Luton airport _after_ you've been through security, which I can't get on board with :-).